# How to find y value of interpolated spline at a desired x value?

Tags: scipy, linear-interpolation

How to extract the y value from spline at a desired x value. For example **@ x= 0.25**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import splev, splrep
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
y = np.sin(x)
spl = splrep(x, y)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 10, 5)
y2 = splev(x2, spl)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', x2, y2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are already doing this by calling `splev(x,tck)`. This outputs an array with the y values at the given x values using the spline described by `tck`. (In your case, x is given by `np.linspace()` and `tck` is the output of `np.splrep()`.)

If you only want to know what the value at e.g. x=.25 is, you would write `y3=splev(0.25, spl)`. Maybe take a look at the documentation for more details: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splev.html